# Call subclass's method from its superclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have two classes, named `Parent` and `Child`, as below. `Parent` is the superclass of `Child`  I can call a method of the superclass from its subclass by using the keyword `super`. Is it possible to call a method of subclass from its superclass?

**Child.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Parent.h"

@interface Child : Parent {

}

- (void) methodOfChild;

@end
```

**Child.m**

```
#import "Child.h"

@implementation Child

- (void) methodOfChild {

    NSLog(@"I'm child");

}

@end
```

**Parent.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Parent : NSObject {

}

- (void) methodOfParent;

@end
```

**Parent.m:**

```
#import "Parent.h"

@implementation Parent

- (void) methodOfParent {

    //How to call Child's methodOfChild here?

}

@end
```

Import "Parent.h" in app delegate's .m file header.

App delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method..

```
Parent *parent = [ [Parent alloc] init];

[parent methodOfParent];

[parent release];
```

Comment: Yes, it is technically possible but this design smells. Really bad. Superclasses aren’t supposed to know about their subclasses.

Comment: I want to achieve same when called from swift, swift in unable to recognize methods in such hierarchy. Can anybody tell how to achive same when first call initialized from a swift class?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can, as Objective C method dispatch is all dynamic. Just call it with `[self methodOfChild]`, which will probably generate a compiler warning (which you can silence by casting `self` to `id`).

But, for the love of goodness, don't do it. Parents are supposed to provide for their children, not the children for their parents. A parent knowing about a sub-classes new methods is a huge design issue, creating a strong coupling the wrong way up the inheritance chain. If the parent needs it, why isn't it a method on the parent?

Comment: Possibly the originating poster is thinking in terms of a C++-style abstract base class (ie, one which defines methods but doesn't provide implementations), and the correct advice is to provide empty implementations on the parent, leaving a child to override them if and only if it's relevant?

Comment: Can we use protocols to do this?

Comment: You could, but you may as well add the implementation to the parent, as a protocol would declare that you have (unless it was optional, which would be a bit….weird). What situation did you want this design for? If @Tommy is right, and this is a abstract base classes code, do as he suggests and declare the method without a body, and have children override it.

Comment: How can we use `id` instead of `self`? Its throwing error if we use `id`

Comment: What error? You don't "use" `id`, you typecast `self` to `id` to avoid the compiler potentially warning that there is no `methodOfChild` selector on `self`.

Comment: Can I use `[self performSelector:@selector(methodOfChild)]`?

Comment: Yes, but there's no benefit. You may as well just call it. Again, I would ask - why?

Comment: How about this for a use case - What if you had multiple classes inheriting from the parent with each class adopting a method with the same name and didn't want to retype the calling of the method in each child (polymorph)? It can be done with delegation I suppose, but is it not just easier to use respondsToSelector?

Answer (score 6):

Technically you can do it. But I suggest you to alter your design. You can declare a protocol and make your child class adopt that protocol. Then you can have to check whether the child adopts that protocol from the super class and call the method from the super class.

Comment: Could you please provide/share some sample code to do it with protocols?

Answer (score 5):

You could use this:

**Parent.m**

```
#import "Parent.h"

@implementation Parent

- (void) methodOfChild {

    // this should be override by child classes
    NSAssert(NO, @"This is an abstract method and should be overridden");    
}

@end
```

The parent knows about the child and child has a choice on how to implement the function.

Answer (score 2):

`super` means "invoke a method dispatching on the parent class", so can use `super` in the subclass because a subclass only has one parent class. A class can have many _sub_classes though, so how would you know which method implementation to call, in the general case? (Hence there is no such thing as a `sub` keyword.)

However, in your example you have two separate methods. There's nothing stopping you (assuming you have *very good reasons* for doing something like this!) from saying, in the parent,

```
- (void) methodOfParent {
    [self methodOfChild];
}
```

Comment: It's helpful to indicate _why_ an answer's incorrect. As it happens, mine's not: obj-c dispatches dynamically, `super` means "perform the method lookup starting with my parent's method dictionary", and you _might_ have a good reason for doing something that otherwise looks horrific.

Answer (score 0):

> if your super has multiple subs then go for this one for the specific
>   sub's method

```
if ([super isKindOfClass:[specificsub class]]) {
                [specificsub methodName];
            }
```

> if your super is dealing with that object (that sub) so sub's method
>   loggedin will be called  an other way is  in you super class

```
super *some = [[sub alloc] init];
[some methodName];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by over riding the method in subclass. That is create a method in parent class and over ride the same in subclass.