# Calling sub class method from the super class in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, subclass, superclass, function-calls

My original question id [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515582/call-subclasss-method-from-its-superclass).

Actually I need more clarification about this problem.

Consider the following scenario:

There are three classes in my project. Say A, B & C.

These 3 classes have some common methods with them. So I created an another class (Say D) in which, I added those common methods.

Now Class D is the parent class and Class A,B & C are child classes. That is, Class A,B & C inherits the properties of D.

I'm having three UIButton's for each child class. Each button in each sub class has some action. But the button's properties like color, frame, image are same in all three classes.

So, I need to do the following things for the buttons in each sub class's:

- init the buttons
- alloc them
- set frame
- set color
- set action (using `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpInsideAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`)
- etc

Except the "set action", everything is same in all child classes (Class A,B & C)

Now my question is, Can I create the button, its properties and action in Class D (Parent class) and Can I write the action method's (`touchUpInsideAction:`) implementation in each child class (Class A,B & C)?

So that, I can reduce my repeated code in my project. Here I'll call the child class's method `touchUpInsideAction:` from the parent class.

Is this right way or should I write button creation and properties for each Class separately?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Instead of assigning the action in the Class D why don't you get the buttons from a common class (say Class D) and assign the action in each of your classes (say Class A)?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class method in Class D. Set all button properties in that method.
Call class method from child class say A. Class method will return object of type UIButton.
Assign the selector and then add that object to the view.

Answer (score 0):

As My Understanding D class should have button with setting all common property and action methods 
. And Child class should be responsible to handle the Action if you want different functionality for every class.

Assume you have added target self  and selector to button in supper class. you have created object of A, B or C. target for button in supper class(D) is self. Self is a representation of object So self will refer to objet of Class A, or B , or c.