# How to fire methods in subclass?

Tags: objective-c, class

If I create ClassA which is subclass from ClassB

```
@interface ClassA : ClassB
```

and I want to fire instance method in subclass ClassA from superclass ClassB

how to do that ?

thanks

Comment: I probably just being picky but wouldn't you create `ClassA` first and have `ClassB` subclass from `ClassA`?

Answer (score 2):

**Design issue. You are going against Inheritance fundamentals.** *Refer OOP books.*

First of all Super class doesn't know whats there in the subclass. However its opposite is allowed.

If you want to do, you need to create an instance of Subclass in Superclass and then call it.

Other ways are by using **Protocol**:

> You can declare a protocol and make your child class adopt that
>   protocol. Then you can have to check whether the child adopts that
>   protocol from the super class and call the method from the super
>   class.

[Call subclass's method from its superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515582/call-subclasss-method-from-its-superclass)

Answer (score 1):

> and I want to fire instance method in subclass ClassA from superclass ClassB

That depends on the situation. If the method is an overridden instance method, you just call it. That is, let's say you've got some methods in ClassB and ClassA overrides some of them:

```
@implementation ClassB
- (void)foo:(ClassB)b
{
    [b bar];
}

- (void)bar
{
    NSLog(@"I'm ClassB");
}
@end

@implementation ClassA
- (void)bar
{
    NSLog(@"I'm ClassA");
}
@end
```

Now, if you have an instance of ClassA:

```
ClassA *a = [[ClassA alloc] init];
```

and you call `foo`

```
[a foo:a];
```

then ClassA's version of `bar` is called and you get this:

```
I'm ClassA
```

On the other hand, if you want ClassB to call some method in ClassA that isn't declared in ClassB, you should first think twice. Having a class know specific things about its subclass(es) is often a sign that you should refactor your code. If the parent class has expectations of the subclass, you usually want to make that clear by declaring the methods in the parent and then requiring those methods to be overridden.

If you're sure you want to do this, one way to do it neatly is to create a protocol that contains the method declarations. `ClassB.h` can then import the protocol header without needing to know specifically about ClassA. So let's say you have a protocol named ProtocolC:

```
@protocol
- (void)baz;
@end
```

and that in some cases you want to require that the object you're using conforms to that protocol. You can specify "an instance of ClassB that adopts ProtocolC" like this:

```
ClassB<ProtocolC>* someObject;
```

If you want to call `baz` from ClassB, you could rewrite `foo:` like this:

```
@implementation ClassB
- (void)foo:(ClassB<ProtocolC>*)b
{
    [b baz];
}
@end
```

Now you just need to adopt ProtocolC in ClassA and implement the methods. There are other possibilities too, but using a protocol here will help keep things neat.

I'd guess that the reason for wanting to do this is that you *know* you're not going to use ClassB directly, but will instead create one or more subclasses and use those instead. That is, ClassB is an abstract class even though Objective-C doesn't differentiate between abstract and concrete classes. If that's the use, you should skip the protocol business, declare your abstract methods in ClassB, and implement those methods in a way that will remind you to provide more useful implementations in your subclass. For example, your "abstract" methods could each throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the method in the superclass and implement it in the subclass.